# Making AJAX work with autocomplete textboxes

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

So im really stuck with this piece of code that im working on. I want to make a function for textboxes that autocomplete the page with Ajax and show the results live on the page with data from the database. This is already working but only with checkboxes. So when a textbox is checked then the page gets updates via AJAX and the results show on the screen.

Now I want the same with the textboxes when you type something in. The textboxes have autocomplete and when you select an item from the list then it should update the page with the results. This is my original AJAX code for the checkboxes but I cant figure out how to use this for the textbox part.

Any help would be appreciated.

AJAX:

```
function makeTable(data) {
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function() {
        var tbl_row = "";
        $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
        })
        tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
    })
    return tbl_body;
}

function getEmployeeFilterOptions(){
    var opts = [];
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            opts.push(this.name);
        }
    });
    return opts;
}

function getEmployeeFilterOptions2(){
    var opts = [];
    $onchange.each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            opts.push(this.name);
        }
    });

    return opts;
}

function updateEmployees(opts){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {filterOpts: opts},
        success: function(records){
            $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
        }
    });
}

var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    var opts = getEmployeeFilterOptions();
    updateEmployees(opts);
});

updateEmployees();
```

Comment: First, you need to think about you'll have to do.

To start, you need to bind the keyboard typing event and define if you start searching at the first or the second character etc... (start searching with one or two character might return too much results) 

https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Then, you'll have to think about the way you render your results (in a basic HTML list ?) and bind the click event to load your resulting page.

You can reuse your ajax call you make sure to handle another HTML markup.

Comment: Thank you, I do know exactly what I want and how to do it but I dont know how to write the code or where to start looking it up for this specific way of code setup.

Comment: I found this library, I might be perfect in your case http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Comment: I had a look at the library but how does that work with a mysql database ?

Comment: It's simple. Change "serviceUrl:'service/autocomplete.ashx'" with "serviceUrl:'submit.php'". Then you'll receive in your php script a $_GET variable nammed "query" : it's your query ! (For example if you typed on your keyboard "Li" your $_GET['query'] will be 'Li'). Process your MySQL query and then be sure to return a JSON array with this format { query:'Li',
 suggestions:['Liberia', 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya', 'Liechtenstein', 'Lithuania'],
 data:['LR', 'LY', 'LI', 'LT'] }